# How to calculate price in non-competitive bidding that bidders will receive?

Tags: fixed-income

Following bids are received in treasury bond auction. Notified amount is Rs.20,000Million. No amount devolves on the RBI/PDs.

No. Of bonds/   Price(Rs.)
46/             110.185
45/             110.1875
44/             110.19
43/             110.1925
42/             110.195
41/             110.1975
40/             110.2
39/             110.2025
At what price will non-competitive bidders receive allotments?

Answer of this question is 110.1980. Please tell me how to calcualte this.

Comment: What are the rules that India uses to determine non-competitive bidder pricing? Looking like right around the 75-80th percentile, but it would be best to find a source for this information and use that instead.